# Setting Color Breaks in ggplot2 using scale_color_gradientn for Raster Data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to set breaks for elevation when plotting raster data but it seems to only be using two of my colors instead of the full set. I have elevation values from -5497 to 1413 and want to use light to dark blue color gradient for negative elevations (water) and grey to black colors for positive elevation (land).

```
Acquired data from NOAA via marmap package
# RASTER BATHY DATA
# From NOAA using marmap package
library(marmap)
library(oce)
Library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

bathy <- getNOAA.bathy(-80, -70, 40, 32, resolution = 1,
    keep = FALSE, antimeridian = FALSE, path = NULL)
bathy_r <- as.raster(bathy)
bathy_r <- as.data.frame(bathy_t, xy = TRUE)
b <- ggplot() +
    geom_raster(bathy_t, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer)) +
    scale_color_gradientn(
    colours = c("midnightblue", "skyblue1", "grey", "black"),
    breaks = c(-5497,-2000, -0.1, 0.2, 1413))
b
```

The resulting plot works but only using the midnightblue and skyblue1 color scheme, no grey or black shows up.

Comment: OP, is the issue you're using `scale_color_gradientn()` instead of `scale_fill_gradientn()`?  The default color scheme is blue and darkblue... so it might look like it's kind of working, but in reality `scale_color_gradientn()` won't do anything here, as it's the wrong aesthetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `marmap` to download bathymetric data, you might as well use `marmap` to plot these data. If you want to use `ggplot2`, it's possible using a few handy `marmap` functions:

```r
library(marmap)
library(ggplot2)

bathy <- getNOAA.bathy(-80, -70, 40, 32, resolution = 1,
                       keep = FALSE, antimeridian = FALSE, path = NULL)
#> Querying NOAA database ...
#> This may take seconds to minutes, depending on grid size
#> Building bathy matrix ...

autoplot(bathy, geom = c("raster", "contour")) +
  scale_fill_etopo()
```

[image]

As explained by [chemdork123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9664796/chemdork123), you can choose any palette you want using `scale_fill_...()` functions instead of `scale_color_...()` functions. A few examples are provided in the `?marmap_autoplot()`.

When using `scale_fill_gradientn()`, you should not use `breaks` to adjust the colors to specific values of depth/altitude, but `values` instead. ANd since `values` expects a numeric vector of values between 0 and 1, you can use `scales::rescale()`. Here is an example with the colors you specified:

```r
autoplot(bathy, geom = c("raster", "contour")) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("midnightblue", "skyblue1", 
                                   "grey", "black"),
                       values = scales::rescale(c(min(bathy), -0.1, 
                                                0, max(bathy))))
```

[image]